# Permissions for SSRS 2008 R2 in Production

Tags: ssrs-2008

We are upgrading to SSRS 2008 R2 on 2008 Server.  We have a production environment that prevents us from having local admin permissions for accounts.  We have been told that we can only have a batch level service account. I assume[d] the Content Manager and System Administrator role can run under this account however we can't seem to get ReportManager running without local admin.  The SSRS database is installed on a separate box.

I'm hoping someone has a set of steps or reference to how we can configure this to work without local admin.

thanks
Marty

Answer (score 0):

When installing SSRS by default there is no place to enter ssrs manager or ssrs credentials. Just set up the endpoints, database, email and a low level account. You would need an admin account initially to access the report manager once. During this time other system level accounts can be created that can match to your admins batch user requirements. I would propose two accounts for the SSRS box.
1. Report User - Can Run Reports Can View
2. Report Admin - Can Update Defs. Can Run Reports

Then deploy reports using ReportAdmin and request reports using ReportUser.

Comment: Thanks!  What we are seeing is when you run the SSRS Configuration Manager we get an error that "local admin" is required.  A few people have suggested that policy "allow logon to this computer" but we can't administer this policy either.